# Problem installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 with flash drive on a Windows 7 laptop

Tags: system-installation

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 from a flash drive to dual-boot with my current Win7 Operating System; after putting the .iso on it with Linux Pen Drive It booted on the flash very well, but when it got to the part of the installation where you choose how you want to install it, I picked "Install alongside Windows 7".

After I clicked "Continue", it restarted my computer, there was a few command lines that came up, then the installer restarted from the beginning. I tried to install over 20 times, but to no avail. Please help! I really like both Ubuntu & Win7, and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't choose install alongside with windows option.Choose something else option.
- Then format the partition you want to install ubuntu into ext4 filesystem.
- After that install ubuntu on the formatted ext4 partition.

Answer (score 0):

**If Computer restarted soon after you told it to install alongside -**

there might be only two reasons for that -

1. Bad write to the USB flash drive.

   For making bootable USB always  use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)  or [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).
2. Corrupted ISO image-

   Use must download it from the only [Official Website.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)